# VB6 check if variable is an object

Tags: function, vb6, parameters

In Visual Basic 6, is there anyway to tell if a variable passed into a function is an object?
I want to be able to test if the variable is null, nothing or empty but only objects can be tested using "Is Nothing".
Any ideas?

Comment: You could consider using `IsNull` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How is the function defined?

If it's `... As Object` then it's either a valid object or `Null`.

If it's `... As Variant` (or no type) then anything can be passed and you can check using `IsEmpty()`, `IsNull()` (Note, NOT a null object, but a null value) or `IsObject()` depending on what exactly you want to check for before the `... Is Nothing` check.

If the parameter is `Optional` then you can use `IsMissing()` but it must be a variant type with no default value.

Also, check out [this article](http://hashvb.earlsoft.co.uk/Null) on the various uses of Null in VB.

Comment: Thanks for that comprehensive answer, the function parameter was an untyped variant and IsObject was what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
IsObject(variable)
```

Not difficult to find

Comment: I don't know how I didn't find that, I accepted deanna's as the 'better' answer but upvoted your answer as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a `TypeOf` operator in VB. Everything that's not a simple value (i.e. Integer etc.) is of type `Object`.

```vb
If TypeOf Variable Is Object Then
  ' ...
End If
```

TypeOf also allows for inheritance checks. For example, mail items in an Outlook folder are both of type `Object` and `Outlook.MailItem`, so you can do actual type-safe checks on a generic Variant variale this way.

Note that `If TypeOf ...` **does not work** with variables that are typed as simple values (i.e. Integer), only with object typed variables (Variant, COM objects, built-in objects).

Comment: Note that Types/UDTs do not count as objects either.

Answer (score 0):

For Variant arguments you can also use the VarType() function and its associated Enum.